# Average Result in a separated row

Tags: t-sql

Is it possible to get an extra row with the average result of a single column?

Example:

[image]

Comment: If you're asking whether it's possible to use a computer to *perform mathematical calculations*... Yes, yes it's possible.  Have you tried?  Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I'm sorry not to have been quite clear. The question is about a query in TSQL

Comment: @JorgeLopes If you used an answer provided by anyone below, people normally "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark. (Letting you know since this seems to be your first post)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I could think of is something like this:

```
with mainCte as (
    SELECT 
        DetailID, Quantity, Value      
    FROM 
        dbo.Detail
),
rowCte as (
    SELECT 
        sumQuantity = sum(Quantity), 
        avgValue = avg(Value)    
    FROM 
        dbo.Detail 
)
select 
    DetailID,
    Quantity,
    Value 
from 
    mainCte

union

select
    DetailID = null,
    Quantity = sumQuantity,
    Value = avgValue
from
    rowCte
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions.

1) `with rollup` - The rollup will do the usual group by, plus roll up to every level possible above it. While this is a good solution, I believe Microsoft has said that it is going to be deprecated soon.

2) `grouping sets`- This is the new rollup solution, where you get to specify every level that it summarizes at, where including a grouping set of`()` will summarize to the highest level possible.

I personally like option 2 better, so I have use that one in my answer.

**Please see my solution below:**

```
create table ##tmp_tbl_main
    (
        customer int not null
        , recv_weight decimal(10,2) not null
        , rej_weight decimal(10,2) not null
    )

insert into ##tmp_tbl_main values (1,100.00,5.00)
insert into ##tmp_tbl_main values (2,120.00,4.00)
insert into ##tmp_tbl_main values (3,230.00,20.00)
insert into ##tmp_tbl_main values (4,120.00,10.00)
insert into ##tmp_tbl_main values (5,50.00,3.00)


select coalesce(cast(a.customer as varchar(10)), 'Total') as Customer
, sum(a.recv_weight) as [Received Weight]
, format(avg(a.rej_weight), '0.00') as [Rejected Weight]
, format(case when a.customer is NULL or sum(a.recv_weight) = 0 then NULL --protecting against div/0 error
       else sum(a.rej_weight)/sum(a.recv_weight)
  end, '0.00%') as [% Rejected]
from ##tmp_tbl_main as a
group by grouping sets
    (
        (a.customer)
        , ()
    )
```

**Results:**

[image: groupingSetsResults]